# OpenCart 2.3.0.2 Vqmod Error Json

Tags: php, json, module, opencart2.x, vqmod

I have installed Vqmod 2.6.3 on Opencart 2.3.0.2, I checked for the permissions, it also shows me the Vqmod in already installed.

The problem I have when I want to install a module with extension manager I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexepected toke < in JSON at position 0.
>
> Warning: ftp_chdir() Can`t change directory vqmod/vqcache/vq2-admin_controller_extension_installer.php on line 298.

I am now on a subdomain with is also configured in the settings-ftp menu of OpenCart.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you rename your admin folder to something else?

Comment: Everything is clean and untouched, except the installing of Vqmod